# Polynomials $q$ satisfying $ q(z, \bar{w}) + q(w, \bar{z}) \le q(z, \bar{z}) + q(w, \bar{w})$ for all complex z and w

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Does there exist a real number $b$ such that the polynomial $q(x,y) := - x y^3 + b x^2 y^2 - x^3 y $ satisfies
$$
q(z, \bar{w}) + q(w, \bar{z}) \le q(z, \bar{z}) + q(w, \bar{w})
\quad \text{for all } z, w\in \mathbb{C}?
$$

Comment: Deleting the question 24 minutes after getting an answer!? Why? May be you didn't think about it, but this is more than a bit rude towards the people who try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : The OP has changed the question. The answer to the current question is that $\color{red}{b\ge 2}$.

---

The original question was that

> Consider the polynomial $q(x,y) := a x y^3 + b x^2 y^2 + a x^3 y $, where $a$ and $b$ are real constants. Suppose that 
>   $$
> q(z, \bar{w}) + q(w, \bar{z}) \le q(z, \bar{z}) + q(w, \bar{w})
> \quad \text{for all } z, w\in \mathbb{C}.
> $$
>   Is it true that $q \equiv 0$, i.e. $a = b = 0$?

The following is to this question :

For $(a,b)$ such that $$\color{red}{b\ge 0\quad\text{and}\quad -\frac b2\le a\le \frac b2}$$
the inequality holds for all $z,w\in\mathbb C$.

The inequality 
$$a z {\bar{w}}^3 + b z^2 {\bar{w}}^2 + a z^3 \bar{w} + a w {\bar{z}}^3 + b w^2 {\bar{z}}^2 + a w^3 \bar{z} \le a z {\bar{z}}^3 + b z^2 {\bar{z}}^2 + a z^3 \bar{z} + a w {\bar{w}}^3 + b w^2 {\bar{w}}^2 + a w^3 \bar{w}$$
is equivalent to
$$a(z {\bar{z}}^3+ z^3 \bar{z} + w {\bar{w}}^3 + w^3 \bar{w}- z {\bar{w}}^3 - z^3 \bar{w} -w {\bar{z}}^3 - w^3 \bar{z})+b( z^2 {\bar{z}}^2 + w^2 {\bar{w}}^2 - z^2 {\bar{w}}^2 - w^2 {\bar{z}}^2)\ge 0$$

$$\iff a(({\bar z}^3-{\bar w}^3)(z-w)+(\bar z-\bar w)(z^3-w^3))+b( z^2 {\bar{z}}^2 + w^2 {\bar{w}}^2 - z^2 {\bar{w}}^2 - w^2 {\bar{z}}^2)\ge 0$$

$$\iff a|z-w|^2(z^2+{\bar{z}}^2+w^2+{\bar{w}}^2+zw+\bar z\bar w)+b|z-w|^2|z+w|^2\ge 0$$

Dividing the both sides by $|z-w|^2$,

$$a(z^2+{\bar{z}}^2+w^2+{\bar{w}}^2+zw+\bar z\bar w)+b|z+w|^2\ge 0$$

(Here, let $z=c+di,w=e+fi$ where $c,d,e,f\in\mathbb R$.)

$$a(2c^2-2d^2+2e^2-2f^2+2ce-2df)+b|z+w|^2\ge 0$$
$$\iff 2a((c+e)^2-(d+f)^2)+b((c+e)^2+(d+f)^2)\ge 0$$
$$\iff (2a+b)(c+e)^2+(b-2a)(d+f)^2\ge 0$$

Hence, for $(a,b)$ such that $$2a+b\ge 0\quad\text{and}\quad b-2a\ge 0$$
the inequality holds for all $z,w\in\mathbb C$.